# How to take care of Erica Gracilis?

Tags: plant-care

I was at the store and I saw an Erica Gracilis and decided to buy it to give a bit of colour to my garden. However, I do not know how to take care of it. I was wondering what is the best location to place this plant, is it indoors or outdoors? In addition, should it be located in direct sun or indirect sun?

Comment: How cold do your winters get? Frost or not?

Answer (score 2):

Full sun is best, but the thing this plant needs is acid soil, so if you don't know your soil ph, best to grow it in a container using ericaceous (for acid loving plants) compost. They prefer well drained soil, so good drainage in whatever container you use is important. It is frost tender, tolerating the occasional drop to -5 deg C, but where you are, I don't think that'll be a problem, having checked, seems your winters have comparatively warm temperatures. More info here https://www.dobbies.com/products/plants/erica/erica-gracilis/